# pagination clickable results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

i am currently working on a pagination system which i am able to make but what i need is the result should have hyperlinks in it. i searched in google but couldn't find the answer.
this is code so far

```
<?php
        //connect to our DB
        mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'password') ;
        mysql_select_db( 'test1' ) ;

        //preparing our variable.
        if( !isset( $_GET['p'] ) ) {$_GET['p']=0;}
        $per_page= 6 ;
        $sql=  " SELECT name FROM pagination " ;
        $sql2= " SELECT name FROM pagination  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['p']."," . $per_page; 
        $query= mysql_query ( $sql2 ) ;
        $rows=  mysql_num_rows ( mysql_query ( $sql ) ) ;
        $page=  ceil ( $rows / $per_page ) ;

        while( $fetch= mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
            echo '<p>' . $fetch['name'] . '</p>' ;
        }

        for( $i=0;$i<$page;$i++ ){

            echo' <a href="pagi.php?p='. ( $i * $per_page ) . '">'. ( $i + 1 ) .'</a> ' ;

        }

    ?>
```

this is what i want if the results are image thumbnails when clicked it should go to the original image
like in http://www.1channel.ch/

Comment: If that's a real password, you shouldn't be putting it here.

Comment: thank u pete i forgot to change

Comment: How is this code wrong? Or not what you wanted?

Comment: the result should have a link attached to it

Comment: if the results are image thumbnails when clicked it should go to the original image

Answer (score 0):

At last line I am not sure you have done right

```
for( $i=0;$i<$page;$i++ ){

        echo' <a href="pagi.php?p='. ( $i * $per_page ) . '">'. ( $i + 1 ) .'</a> ' ;

    }
```

it will produce like

```
href="pagi.php?p=0" => 1 
href="pagi.php?p=6" => 2
href="pagi.php?p=12" => 3
```

Multiples of 6 ($per_page) you are passing to param 'p'

Change ( $i * $per_page ) to $i

It may resolve your problem

Comment: Actually that is not my problem at all. what i am saying is if the results are image thumbnails when clicked it should go to the original image. this is what i want.

Comment: Like this ?? <a href="link_to_org_img" > <img src="thumnail.jpg" > </a>

Comment: results means sql query results ?? (we can store image too in DB)

Comment: is that linking part should be done in html? can't i store data in database and use it?

Comment: Sorry to say ,still i am not sure on ur doubt.. Are you trying to build image gallery where you have list of thumbnails and on a click over it will show you a full sized image like : http://geneliafans.com/gallery/displayimage.php?album=random&cat=0&pos=-9710

Answer (score 0):

> this is what i want if the results are image thumbnails when clicked it should go to the original image

If "name" returned from SQL is the name of the image that you want to display then try like this :

```
 while( $fetch= mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) 
   {
        $org_img_name=$fetch['name']; // some_image.jpg
        echo "<p> <a href='your/path/of/image/$org_img_name'> <img src='your/path/of/image/thumb_img_name.jpg' ></a></p>" ;
    }
```

Comment: Try it but i dont see any relation between ur question and pagination